# Linux Mint 17.2 Nemo context menu has no Dropbox entry

Tags: linux-mint

I have Dropbox installed from the software center and it runs fine. I just went to a file in my Dropbox and right clicked on it to share it's public link and realized there is no Dropbox menu entry in my Nemo right click menu. Is there any way to fix this?

Linux Mint 17.2 64-bit. Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the nemo-dropbox plugin?

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-dropbox
```

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers:
I had the same problem, and the provided solution (installing nemo-dropbox), did not work for me.

I fixed it by turning off "support for indicators" in System settings-> general, (and restarting). This solution was inspired by the support item on: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installation-and-desktop-app/Systray-menu-Cinnamon/td-p/130030, although i did not have to turn it back on to work.

If this does not work either, maybe other solutions provided there may help.